# Understanding JavaScript events and applying jQuery events/plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

I have a bunch of jQuery functions that use the .on event because I want to prevent reapplying the event to the same element.

However some people created plugins (e.g. Owl Carousel) and I don't know how to prevent this event from reapplying.

Currently I am using the plugin as following:

HTML:

```
<div class="init-owl"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.init-owl').owlCarrousel();
$('.init-owl').removeClass('init-owl');
```

Whenever a second element gets loaded in the page using e.g. AJAX, I want to only apply the event to the newly added element.

1. Question: What I dont understand is how the event stays stuck to the DOM?
2. To better grip what is happening, I was wondering how an event in general gets connected to the DOM?
3. Is there a better way to prevent events applying to the same DOM elements?

If I wish to write my own plugins, I would need to know how javascript works, right?

Comment: `event.preventDefault` will prevent normal behavior of an event so that you can custom define the event handler.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: How does that answer the above?

Comment: I was answering this part of your question:
"Is there a better way to prevent events applying to the same DOM elements?"

Comment: Does e.preventDefault() also prevent the same event from triggering twice? E.g. if I add a click event to the body  that console.logs something twice, does it only write the log once if I add e.preventDefault to the function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: What I dont understand is how the event stays stuck to the DOM?

Once an event is bound to an object, it gets removed when the object gets garbaged collected. So if a DOM element is really gone and there are no references to it, then the event will get swept up as well.

> To better grip what is happening, I was wondering how an event in general gets connected to the DOM?

I'm not sure how far you want to dive into this. Maybe it would help if you stop thinking about the DOM and events and look more at just regular events bound to objects. Basically an object does something, or something is done to it and some underlying code (in the browser's code in this case) triggers an event on that object. The implementations between browsers may differ, but basically you will have a key or string (the event name) that maps to a collection of functions. When you add an event listener, you add another function to this collection. Then when something triggers that event, it iterates through the functions and executes them. That's a real basic explanation, but I hope it makes things a little more clear.

> Is there a better way to prevent events applying to the same DOM elements?

Make sure you don't add the events again by writing better code. I don't believe you can dive down into an element and look to see if it has events bound to it. You can however change your jQuery selector to only target newly added elements. If you have to, mark the elements that you have added events to with a class or something. Then you could target your elements by doing `$('.init-owl:not(.already-bound)')`. There is a better solution to your problem, I can assure you, but we might need more context and code to see a better way to help you.

**EDIT:**

You can look into [jQuery's `off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove events. That may help you too.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. As a starting web developer in a small company, the only way to gain knowledge and understanding is via the internet. I really appreciate it:)